# Create resources iterating through the values of a map rather key - terraform

Tags: terraform

I couldn’t figure out how I can loop through the sum of values of the below map.

```
variable "images" {
  default = {
    "rhel-8-factory-os-ready" = {
       "availability_zone" = "eu-fra-1ah"
       "flavor" = 4
       "instance_count" = 2
       "image_name" = "rhel-8-factory-os-ready"
    },
    "rhel-7-factory-os-ready" = {
       "availability_zone" = "eu-fra-1ai"
       "instance_count" = 3
       "flavor" = 3
       "image_name" = "rhel-7-factory-os-ready"
    },
    "rhel-6-factory-os-ready" = {
       "availability_zone" = "eu-fra-1ah"
       "instance_count" = 3
       "flavor" = 3
       "image_name" = "rhel-6-factory-os-ready"
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I’ve to iterate through the sum of `instance_count` attribute of the all the keys & create instances based on the `instance_count`.

I could calculate the sum of `instance_count`, with below inbuilt functions.

```
locals {
  list_sum = length(flatten([for i in var.images: range(i["instance_count"])]))
}
```

How can I iterate through the `list_sum` variable & create the resources based on `instance_count`?

I created below lists to create resources ::

```
locals {
  list_images = tolist(keys(var.images))
  list_instance_count = [for i in var.images: i["instance_count"]]
  list_flavors = [for i in var.images: i["flavor"]]
  list_image_names = [for i in var.images: i["image_name"]]
  list_availability_zones = [for i in var.images: i["availability_zone"]]
}
```

My resource ::

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance" {
  count = local.list_sum
  image_name = element(local.list_image_names, count.index +1 )
  flavor_id = element(local.list_flavors, (count.index + 1) )
  name = element(local.list_image_names, (count.index + 1) )
  security_groups = var.security_group
  availability_zone = element(local.list_availability_zones, (count.index + 1) )
  key_pair = "foptst"
  network {
    name = var.network_name
  }
}
```

By now, you may be knowing that my iteration is incorrect. My resource block has to create the number of resources based on instance_count var ie., 2 instances of `rhel-8-factory-os-ready`, 3 instances of `rhel-7-factory-os-ready` and 3 instances of `rhel-6-factory-os-ready`.

Because of incorrect looping, I couldn’t get it. It would be great if someone could help me how to iterate properly to create resources as expected.

Many Thanks in advance,
Harsha

Comment: Perhaps the not-yet-released Terraform feature of Resource for_each could be the one (https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/) to use?

Comment: terraform 0.12 is already released, I'm using it & `for_each` is available. I know my dataset is complex but perfectly valid. I used `setproduct` to use `for_each` but it is generating `3*3 =9` resources wherein I need to create only 8

Comment: I tried to use `dynamic`, didn't work at all

Comment: Please read carefully. It says "Unfortunately we will not be able to fully complete this feature for the Terraform 0.12 initial release, but we plan to include this in a subsequent release"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
locals {
  expanded_image_names = flatten([
    for key, value in var.images : [
      for counter in range(var.images[key]["instance_count"]): var.images[key]["image_name"]
    ]
  ])
}

output "expanded_image_names" {
  value = local.expanded_image_names
}
```

This will produce:

```
expanded_image_names = [
  "rhel-6-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-6-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-6-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-7-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-7-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-7-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-8-factory-os-ready",
  "rhel-8-factory-os-ready",
]
```

Then use them:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance" {
  count = local.list_sum
  image_name = element(local.expanded_image_names, count.index +1 )  # <-----
  ... # Do similar for the others.

  key_pair = "foptst"
  network {
    name = var.network_name
  }
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks, this creating resources as expected. But, there is a shortcoming as it uses `count`. But, that was my choice. This will only affect when I increase/decrease the count which was discussed [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/when-i-change-count-to-for-each-the-resource-will-recreate/2296/2). Unless, I use a proper key, the terraform can't guarantee the changes the way I expected. 

Nevertheless, many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @harshavmb, have you tried for_each instead of count? https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count